# Can I trigger pipelines in other repos when I create a PR?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have 3 repos in Azure DevOps. We use Azure Pipelines to run our CI/CD chain.
Repo A is a toolset used by the other repos.
Repo B uses A as submodule, and C uses A as git submodule.

When creating a PR in repo A, we want to trigger test Pipelines in repo B and C and have the status in repo A's PR. B and C's pipelines/runs should use the PR commit when running their tests. This to avoid that changes in repo A breaks repo B and C upon release.

Our problem is that we want to make sure to use the right commit of repo A (the one in the PR) and to get the test results for repo B and C in to the PR.

Comment: Have you got a submodule or subtree relationship between A, B and C? (Assuming you're using git).

Comment: No, B uses A as submodule. C uses A as submodule. No other relation.s

Comment: You can trigger one pipeline from another one, however, if you want to B and C to test based on your A repository (meaning the last commit ID), you'd need an intermediate repository, because Í'm assuming our C and B repositories statically define from which branch they'd have to pull the changes right? Furthermore, I think your pipeline design might be a little bit misleading. But without actually seeing what you are doing is a shoot in the dark here.

Comment: To explain a little more of the background.
Repo A is a toolset for the repos. It provides components that B and C uses in their product. Our fear is that changes in A might break existing functionality in B and C and therefore we want to create CI/CD pipeline.

For different reasons we can't create a mono repo with A, B and C.
B and C are actually several more repos than just 2.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible through build-validation policies in a branch policy, but it won't be straight forward.

Under the hood, when you specify a build in the build-validation policy, azure-devops will queue the pipeline on a temporary branch `/refs/pull/<id>/merge`. It queues the pipeline with [several additional variables that represent pull request meta-data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services). When that build completes, it sends a status message back to pull-request to indicate whether the conditions were met.

Microsoft has a few articles on how to create a [custom PR server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=azure-devops) or using a [Function App to create custom branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=azure-devops). These could be used as an approach, but both articles suggest that they invoke based on a webhook when the *pull request is created*. Both articles mention how to send custom PR Status messages back to the PR.

If you want more control over manually re-queueing the build-validation, you could in theory also create a pipeline that triggers the other pipelines in the other repos.

1. Define a build-validation pipeline that can be used to trigger the other pipelines. This is equivalent to using a Webhook/Function app, but the main difference is the UI in the Pull Request provides options to retrigger the build.
2. This build-validation pipeline reads the queue-time variables to identify which PR is being executed. You can add logic to this pipeline to use the Azure DevOps REST API to queue the pipelines in the other repos/projects. When queuing these pipelines, pass the details of the pull request meta-data as queue-time variables in the body of the message.
3. When the external pipeline runs, read the queue time parameters to record which PR initiated the build. Add some custom logic to include checking out the `/refs/pull/<id>/merge` branch for your submodules then Build + Test.
4. When the external pipeline completes, post the PR Status back to the originating PR.
5. Modify the branch policy to [indicate the Build Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pr-status-policy?view=azure-devops) from the other pipelines as Required.